# Do I need to kasher the grill I used to kasher my liver?

Tags: cooking-bishul, parts-of-the-body, kashering-kosherization, keilim

I was looking at meat at the local butcher-shop and noticed that the packaged liver (un-kashered) mentioned that it could be cooked on a grill. However, I have always heard that liver needs its own kli (vessel), due to the excess amount of blood involved. If I use the grill, do I need to kasher the grate?

Comment: I prefer writing questions in 1st person, if they could apply to me, rather than being more of a theoretical pursuit.

Comment: Has the liver been kashered yet?? I thought you couldn't buy stuff not-kashered in America unless you kill it yourself....

Comment: Also, see beginning of SA YD 73 -- the ONLY acceptable way (לכתחילה) to kasher liver is by roasting

Comment: @Shokhet, it has not been kashered, however, it mentions specifically that a grill can be used on the packaging. If it helps, the hashgacha is from the Nirbatter Rov (R' Aharon Teitelbaum miSatmar).

Comment: Subsequent research ( = asking my parents ;) has revealed that when you buy a chicken whole it comes with the liver un-kashered, and it must be roasted....I never buy food, and hence did not know.

Comment: i think rav ovadia paskens the grate stays kosher flieshig, but the drippings are not kosher so if it drips in the oven it will become not kosher

Comment: While this topic is up, can I put the liver in an aluminum pan, put the oven on broil, and have the blood drip into the pan? It shouldn't traif the whole oven I would thionk? When the liver is grilled, I throw out the pan. Sound OK?

Comment: @DanF Sounds like a treif liver. You got to let the blood drip *away* from the liver. Otherwise you haven't really removed it at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA - how about if I put a grate in the aluminum pan so that the liver rests on the grate and the blood drips in the pan?

Comment: @DanF see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52464/5120

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Star K article](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-beef-liver.htm), cited by Dan F in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52464/5323):

> ...The pan will become treif. The rack or grate should not be used for
>   anything except kashering liver, unless proper kosherization
>   procedures are employed to kasher the grates, racks, and/or utensils.
>
> Any utensil used in the broiling process, such as a fork, should be
>   set aside and used exclusively for livers. It is a meritorious
>   practice to burn the fork and all the utensils used in the broiling
>   process in fire before the next time liver is to be kashered.....