# Kasher a liver or unsalted meat

Tags: halacha, meat, kashering-kosherization

I understand that To prepare a liver  to eat (not raw (maybe raw ok just to wash?)) and unsalted meat (without salting for 18min) We need to roust for the fire to remove its blood

I understand that roasting originally was Directly over the fire

How is it done now?

---

What are the halichik opinions

if roasting over electrically produced heat?

if the fire is not directly under the meat?

If there is a peace of metal between the fire and the meat (as is made in gas grills to protect the fire from the seeping juices)?

Is their a certain distance (or a certain temperature?) it needs to be from the fire? (Or it can be made into jerky under small temperatures)

Comment: Slightly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43628

Comment: @Fred the comments there have similar questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from [Star K](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-beef-liver.htm)

> **The Fire**
>
> It is preferable to broil the liver on a fire source that is directly
>   below the liver. If that is not feasible, one may broil liver from a
>   heat source above the liver. Hence, it would be permissible to broil
>   liver in a broiler or in an electric oven, if that is the only
>   broiling source available. If the oven or broiler is used for kosher
>   food as well, care should be taken to assure the blood does not
>   splatter onto the oven or broiler cavity. Splatter blood will make the
>   oven or broiler walls treif. A practical solution is to place a pan
>   under the rack or grate to catch the dripping blood and juices. The
>   pan will become treif. The rack or grate should not be used for
>   anything except kashering liver, unless proper kosherization
>   procedures are employed to kasher the grates, racks, and/or utensils.
>   …
>
> It is customary to turn the liver or the liver slices during the
>   broiling process from time to time to facilitate a more even and
>   uniform broiling. It is also customary to broil liver until the outer
>   juices have ceased flowing, and the liver is dry on the outside. The
>   liver need not be burnt.

Comment: Just use aluminum foil or similar underneath, the blood will go into that making it treif but you can just throw it away