# Roasting unsalted meat

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, kashering-kosherization

What are the customs in the process of making meat edible by removing the blood through roasting?

Specifically after the roasting do I need to wash the meat to eat it (not to cook it afterwards)?

What is the Sefardi custom?

What is the Ashkenazi custom?

If yes what can I do to have a dry Barbecue taste?

Comment: How long has the meat been left unsalted?

Comment: Was the meat washed before the roasting?

Comment: @mefaresh if I understand you I am interested both cases (more and less then 3 days)

Comment: @mefaresh I did not know it will make a difference if washed before roasting?

Comment: @Yishai - I'm quite certain there was a M.Y. liver question on this. If you find it, this Q may be a dupe.

Comment: @danf meat maybe less strict then liver

Comment: @DanF, [This](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52459/kasher-a-liver-or-unsalted-meat) is probably what you mean. Not convinced it is a dupe, as that asks for the roasting procedure, this asks for the washing-after-roasting requirements.

Comment: @hazoriz  than 3 days unsalted some poskim holds that roasting wouldn't help. And hadacha is required before roasting iirc

Comment: Refer to Y.D. 76:3. There are differing opinions on what to do before as well as after roasting the meat.